# Let careers profile say "open ONLY to working remotely"

Tags: feature-request, jobs, profile-page

I'd like to have my profile say something like "Active candidate interested in full-time remote position," to indicate that I'm looking to change jobs, but only in favor of a position working remotely.

Currently the closest we can get is "Active candidate interested in full-time position. Open to working remotely," which suggests that I'm actively exploring both remote and non-remote positions.

Is there any way to do this?  Will there ever be?

Comment: "*Is there any way to do this?*" Hope not, you've just requested it to be implemented ;) "*Will there ever be?*" Hopefully, seems like a good idea. I suggest changing your proposed "*Active candidate interested in full-time remote position*" to have "only" on the end. As your wording is still not explicitly *only* this option (you essentially only removed the word "open"). I know this can be debated, and I don't use careers area to be fair, but you might still get asked "Where are you, would you consider working in XYZ" - without the "only" wording.

Comment: I will sponsor this feature.